# not able to understand the error in this code

Tags: android

1.the Msg string value is succesfully recieved in another activity
2.the d and Time int value are not recieved successfully in another activity

```
    EditText Msgbody=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    Msg=Msgbody.getText().toString();

    EditText Datebody = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateText);
    d=Integer.parseInt(Datebody.getText().toString());

    EditText Timebody=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    Time=Integer.parseInt(Timebody.getText().toString());

    Intent m=new Intent(this,Listview.class);
    Bundle extra=new Bundle();
    extra.putString("Message",Msg);
    extra.putInt("Date",d);
    extra.putInt("Time",Time);
    m.putExtras(extra);
    startActivity(m);
```

3.intent recieving code

```
    Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    String message1=extra.getString("Message");
    TextView msg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msgtext);
    msg.setText(message1);

    int D=-1;
    D=extra.getInt("Date",0);
    if(D>0){
        TextView dt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        if(dt!=null)
            dt.setText(valueOf(D));}

    int time1=extra.getInt("Time",0);
    TextView ti=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    if(ti!=null)
        ti.setText(valueOf(time1));
```

Comment: Off Topic - Your variable names are very confusing. Now coming to the topic before sending these name value pairs, are you checking if they are empty?

Comment: no, i'm not check that but i give intger values through edittext

Comment: Dude, you should check if your values are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your receiving intent you should fetch the values like:

```
if(extra.getExtras() != null)
    date = extra.getExtras().getInt("date");
```

Also please check if your variables aint empty before you pass them

Comment: variables are not empty before passing. is there any logical error in the code?

Comment: hey i am really sorry ihave taken wrong id of my date and time that's why this problem is arrived but thanks for your attention